# Targum of Elokim

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, pronunciation, targumin

The Targum uses yod yod for both Hashem and Elokim unless both are mentioned together. Should the yod yod be understood generically and pronounced Elokim when the chumash says Elokim, or should it be pronounced Hashem as it generally represents.

Comment: It is Adonai. The Targum means to distance people from the possible notion that there is multiplicity in God, so it chooses to use just one name, Adonai, wherever possible.